# Quick access to "Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features"

Tags: windows, windows-8, control-panel

Is there any cmd command to open "Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features"? Or is there any way to access it quickly?

Comment: Just paste that path into any Windows Explorer Window, or create a shortcut,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run the `appwiz.cpl` command either from Windows 7/8 research bar, Windows run dialog box (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcut) or from a command prompt.

Of course you can also create a shortcut to `appwiz.cpl`.

You can find a list of Control Panel commands in the Wikipedia [Control Panel (Windows)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Panel_%28Windows%29) article.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a pure CMD solution with no helper file, do

```
start ::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{7B81BE6A-CE2B-4676-A29E-EB907A5126C5}
```

You can optionally use `explorer` as the command (instead of `start`) and/or put `shell:` at the beginning of the long string
(i.e., `start shell:::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB0…`). 
I discovered this by creating a shortcut and then examining the shortcut with Notepad. 
I then Googled the strings and found several pages, including [Windows 8 shell commands full list (The most comprehensive list of shell locations in Windows 8)](http://winaero.com/blog/the-most-comprehensive-list-of-shell-locations-in-windows-8), that list these and many other codes for Control Panel items, and places that don't have ordinary pathnames, like "Computer" and "Recycle Bin".

Answer (score 1):

It’s present in Explorer’s toolbar when viewing “Computer”:

[image: haha]

Explorer can opened quickly by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

This solution works starting from Windows XP, though it’s only visible when the folder tree is not there.

Comment: The. I had forgotten that there is such button. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way: <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> - <kbd>P</kbd>. P may be language dependent, mine is Dutch (e.g. <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> - <kbd>F</kbd> for English).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest...

Right-click/drag to desktop; make Shortcut.